# Embedded attribute generates java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field MyModel to java.lang.String

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've trying to use an @Embedded id type and it's throwing:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field cmb.model.CertificateId.id to java.lang.String
  #0: sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
  #1: sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
  #2: sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
  #3: sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
  #4: java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
  #5: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71)
  #6: org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:59)
  #7: org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValues(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:65)
  #8: org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValues(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:92)
  #9: org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValues(ComponentType.java:443)
  #10: org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGetValues(ComponentType.java:384)
  #11: org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:337)
  #12: org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:53)
  #13: org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:648)
  #14: org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPreparedStatement(Loader.java:2169)
  #15: org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2146)
  #16: org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2078)
  #17: org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2056)
  #18: org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
  #19: org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:350)
  #20: org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2887)
  #21: org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2869)
  #22: org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2701)
  #23: org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2696)
  #24: org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
  #25: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
  #26: org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
  #27: org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1415)
  #28: org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565)
  #29: org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
  #30: org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
```

My Certificate class has a CertificateId that I want to make embedded.  There's a single attribute of CertificateId which is "id" (String).  I've looked over similar posts here and else where but I don't see any solutions that work for me.

My Certificate class looks like this:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "Certificate")
public class Certificate extends ModelCore {
    @Embedded()
    @AttributeOverrides({
          @AttributeOverride( name = "id", column = @Column(name = "CertificateId")),
        })
    private CertificateId certificateId = null;

    public CertificateId getCertificateId() {
      return certificateId;
    }
    public void setCertificateId(CertificateId newCertificateId) {
      certificateId = newCertificateId;
    }
    public void setCertificateId(String id) {
      certificateId = new CertificateId(id);
    }

    ...
}
```

My CertificateId class:

```
@Embeddable()
public class CertificateId extends AbstractEntityId {

    protected CertificateId() {

    }
    public CertificateId(String id) {
        setId(id);
    }

//  @Basic()
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id = null;

    public String id() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String newId) {
        id = newId;
    }
    @Override
    protected int hashOddValue() {
        return 83811;
    }
    @Override
    protected int hashPrimeValue() {
        return 263;
    }
}
```

and the subclass AbstractEntityId:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntityId {

    public abstract String getId();
    protected abstract int hashOddValue();
    protected abstract int hashPrimeValue();
    
    public String id() {
        return getId();
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
        boolean equalObjects = false;

        if (anObject != null && this.getClass() == anObject.getClass()) {
            AbstractId typedObject = (AbstractId) anObject;
            equalObjects = this.id().equals(typedObject.id());
        }

        return equalObjects;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hashCodeValue =
                + (this.hashOddValue() * this.hashPrimeValue())
                + this.id().hashCode();

        return hashCodeValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getId();
    }

}
```